# Зависание одной формы во время работы другой

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, циклы

Есть две формы: `Form1` и `Form2`. Они взаимодействую друг с другом, и при выполнении определенных действий во второй форме запускается цикл, идущий без перерыва, пока не произойдет нужное событие. Так вот, нужно, чтобы даже при исполнении цикла второй формы работала и первая, а дальше и вторая, третья, четвертая...Как же мне это сделать? Периодичность выполнения действий в цикле - от 1 до 10 секунд, не больше.

Comment: Выполнять действия по таймеру или в другом потоке (с помощью System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker).

Comment: @JaponDemon, сижу, сижу, но никак не могу запустить BackgrowndWorker. Просто не запускается, и все, хотя ошибок нет.